# Как правильно использовать MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я юзаю денвер и захожу в phpmyadmin http://localhost/Tools/phpMyAdmin/. но как я понимаю эти базы данных, которые я создаю они остаются на этом компьютере и с другого я уже их не увижу... как вообще правильно это всё юзать , чтоб можно было с любого компа зайти и тд?

Comment: *с другого я уже их не увижу* Это почему же? настроить MySQL на приём коннектов извне, создать пользователей - и общайтесь.

Comment: Дайте х-человеку логин / пароль от phpmyadmin, и он сможет увидеть с другого компьютера вашу бд ;)

Comment: только вместо localhost подставьте ip-адрес вашей машины в сети

Comment: но вот я не ввожу пароль или логин, когда создаю бд...тогда, чтоб создать бд надо создать пользователя там где раздел "добавить пользователя"  и тогда уже делать бд? а потом уже заходить с другого компьютера по этому логину и паролю?

Comment: добавить пользователя можно уже для созданной бд

Comment: нееее, дело не в этом. я вот делаю таблицy на своем компе(root) и мне надо посмотреть ее на другом , а у меня нету хостинга где эта залита , а с другого компа я уже не могу свое посмотреть или могу ?

Comment: Вам нужен даже не MySQL, а сделать свою машинку доступной с интернета. Есть белый IP адрес (выделенный IP адрес) от провайдера? Тогда проблем нет. Но я боюсь что вы за кучей роутеров, поэтому смотрите в сторону Dynamic dns. И, намного лучше, арендуйте свой VDS или шаред хостинг, это будет в сто раз лучше.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы с другого юзать нужно иметь хост, чтобы был сервер не локальный и уже там зарегистрировать phpmyadmin, попробуй webhost000

Comment: @Let'ssayPie в этом ответе содержится решение вопроса, хотя и отвратительно сформулированное ("если вам нужна база данных, доступ к которой нужно будет получать с разных хостов интернета - купите хостинг и разместите базу данных на нём")

Comment: ну знаете, как задан вопрос, такой и ответ